# $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^3(\sin x)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

There are closed forms for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)\,\mathrm dx\,$ and $\,\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^2(\sin x)\,\mathrm dx\,$ but I can’t seem to find a closed form for $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^3(\sin x)\,\mathrm dx\;.$$

How would I calculate it?

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln^3(\sin(x))\text{ d}x = -\frac1{16}\pi^3\ln(4) - \frac1{16}\pi\ln^3(4)-\frac34 \pi \zeta(3)$$ where $\zeta(x)$ is the Riemann Zeta function

Comment: I believe you can use complex analysis to solve this analytically without software. Something similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3nTBisgrh0

Comment: https://youtu.be/f9pR30LRnzs

Comment: see https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1729326p11207068

Comment: $\ldots=\left.\frac{\partial^3}{\partial s^3}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^s x\,dx\right|_{s=0}$ which is a polygamma spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that $$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln ^3(\sin x) d x=\left.\frac{\partial^3}{\partial a^3} I(a)\right|_{a=0}
$$
where
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^a x d x=\frac{1}{2}B\left (\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

\begin{aligned}
&\quad  \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}(\mathrm{~B}(x, y)) \\&=\left[\left(\psi^{(0)}(x)-\psi^{(0)}(x+y)\right)^3+3\left(\psi^{(1)}(x)-\psi^{(1)}(x+y)\right) \left(\psi^{(0)}(x)-\psi^{(0)}(x+y)\right)\\  +\psi^{(2)}(x)-\psi^{(2)}(x+y)\right] \mathrm{B}(x, y)
\end{aligned}

Putting $x=\frac{a+1}{2} $ and $y=\frac{1}{2} $ at $a=0$ in the derivative yields

\begin{aligned}
 & \quad \frac{\partial^3}{\partial a^3} B\left(\frac{a+1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{\pi}{8}[(\left.\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi(1)\right)^3+3\left(\psi^{\prime}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi^{\prime}(1)\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi(1)\right) \\
&\left. \quad  +\psi^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi^2(1)\right] \\
&=\frac{\pi}{8}\left[(-\gamma-\ln 4+\gamma)^3+3\left(\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)(-\gamma-\ln \psi+\gamma)\right. +(-14 \zeta(3)+2 \zeta(3))] \\
&= \frac{\pi}{8}\left(-\ln ^3 4-\pi^2 \ln 4-12 \zeta(3)\right)
\end{aligned}

Hence $$\boxed{I=-\frac{\pi}{16}\left(\ln ^3 4+\pi^2 \ln 4+12 \zeta(3) \right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica says:
$$
-\frac{1}{16}\pi\left(12\zeta(3)+\log^3(4)+\pi^2\log(4)\right)$$